# How to apply multiple condition on rows without changing the result from the previous condition?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have pandas dataframe where i need to apply multiple conditions. Here is the sample of my df

```
Cond           Samp        
A_B_C          Org
A_B_C          Org
A_B_C          Sea
A_B_C          Paid
```

I need a new column based on this condition

```
df['New'] = df[df['Samp'] == 'Org']['Cond'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[0]
df['New'] = df[df['Samp'] == 'Sea']['Cond'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[0]
df['New'] = df[df['Samp'] == 'Paid']['Cond'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)[2]
```

desired output:

```
Cond           Samp        New
A_B_C          Org         A
A_B_C          Org         A
A_B_C          Sea         A
A_B_C          Paid        C
```

Comment: Please explain your conditions. What is `df["Sea"]`? There is only two columns in your sample namely `Cond` and `Samp`.

Comment: I edited... I made mistake.. Now its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which takes a `condlist` and a `choicelist` and replaces values based on which condition is matched:

```
splits = df['Cond'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)
df['New'] = np.select(
    [df['Samp'].eq('Org') | df['Samp'].eq('Sea'), df['Samp'].eq('Paid')],
    [splits[0], splits[2]]
)
```

Condition 1. `df['Samp'].eq('Org') | df['Samp'].eq('Sea')` replaces with `splits[0]`

Condition 2. `df['Samp'].eq('Paid')` replaces with `splits[2]`

`splits` is calculated once to keep from splitting multiple times:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  A  B  C
2  A  B  C
3  A  B  C
```

`df`:

```
    Cond  Samp New
0  A_B_C   Org   A
1  A_B_C   Org   A
2  A_B_C   Sea   A
3  A_B_C  Paid   C
```

---

Naturally this could also be 3 separate conditions:

```
splits = df['Cond'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)
df['New'] = np.select(
    [df['Samp'].eq('Org'), df['Samp'].eq('Sea'), df['Samp'].eq('Paid')],
    [splits[0], splits[0], splits[2]]
)
```

---

Depending on the size of the DataFrame performance may also become a factor:

[image: perfplot]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot


def gen_data(n):
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'Cond': 'A_B_C',
        'Samp': np.random.choice(['Org', 'Sea', 'Paid'], n)
    })


cond = {'Org': 0, 'Sea': 0, 'Paid': 2}


def apply(df):
    df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Cond'].split('_')[cond[x['Samp']]],
                         axis="columns")
    return df


def np_select(df):
    splits = df['Cond'].str.rsplit("_", expand=True)
    df['New'] = np.select(
        [df['Samp'].eq('Org') | df['Samp'].eq('Sea'), df['Samp'].eq('Paid')],
        [splits[0], splits[2]]
    )
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(5)
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            apply,
            np_select
        ],
        labels=[
            'apply @Corralien',
            'np_select @Henry Ecker'
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a dictionary to map conditions:

```
cond = {'Org': 0, 'Sea': 0, 'Paid': 2}

df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Cond'].split('_')[cond[x['Samp']],
                     axis="columns")
```

```
>>> df
    Cond  Samp New
0  A_B_C   Org   A
1  A_B_C   Org   A
2  A_B_C   Sea   A
3  A_B_C  Paid   C
```